# Xcode executable cannot find glsl files

Tags: macos, opengl, xcode4.5, glut

This is the first time I try to learn OpenGL, I'm following the examples of a book. I'm doing it under OS X 10.8 with Xcode. The code is the following:

```
#include "Angel.h"

const int numPoints = 5000;
typedef vec2 point2;

void init(){

    point2 points[numPoints];
    point2 vertices[3] = {
        point2(-1.0, -1.0), point2(0.0, 1.0), point2(1.0, -1.0)
    };

    points[0] = point2(0.25, 0.5);

    for (int k = 1; k < numPoints; k++) {
        int j = rand()%3;
        points[k] = (points[k-1]+vertices[j])/2.0;
    }

    GLuint program = InitShader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint abuffer;
    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &abuffer);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(abuffer);

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

}


void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numPoints);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles. But when I try to execute it the window does not appear. The problem arises when I call the `init()` function. Without it the window appears but with a black background. With it, there's no window. The code can be found [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/).

**UPDATE**

Apparently the program is exiting in the line `GLuint program = InitShader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");` because it's not finding the shader-files. How can I tell the program to use the files? I mean I have the `.glsl` files in the same folder as the `.h` and `.cpp` but when Xcode builds the project the executable is not in the same place as the `.glsl` files. How to solve this within Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow Below Step:**

Select the project on the left panel.

Select the target and then select `Build Phases`

There you should fin a button called `Add Build Phase`

There will appear a box where you have to select the files (there's a little `+`sign). And be sure you selected `Destination: Products directory`

Build the project, run it and now it should work !!

Answer (score 2):

The GLSL files are loaded at the runtime of the program. So it's not XCode that doesn't find the files, but your program. The most likely cause is, that you used a relative path for the files (like in the code snippet you provided), but started your program with a working path that doesn't match up with the hardcoded file locations. Usually your program binary is built into a dedicated build directory.

A quick fix is copying the GLSL files into the same directory as the binary. The proper solution would be to place the filed in a well known location. In MacOS X you can use Application bundles for this. See in the MacOS X developer docs how to place application resources into the Application bundle and how to access them. XCode also provides tools to automatically copy files into the generated bundle.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right, it's not Xcode it's the program the one not finding the files. My mistake.

Comment: Could you point out some info about the Application bundle, I already searched about that but seems everything is iOS-oriented... Tried a few but couldn't make my files copy to the exec directory

Comment: @BRabbit27: See here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH8-SW1 and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBundle and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i

Comment: @BRabbit27 and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100 – BTW I only was aware about that bundles exist. I just dug those documents up using Google and some educated guesses which links in the Apple Developer Docs to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If Xcode isn't importing the files, then check if it's adding it to the resource folder by going to Your project Name in the file chooser, build phases, Copy Bundle Resources and make sure your 2 files are in there.

Comment: Ok. I found the Copy Bundle Resources, but still not copying the files.

Comment: Are your shaders inside Copy Bundle Resources then?

Comment: Yes they are inside the Copy Bundle Resources phase

Comment: Can you show us the code for your function `InitShader()` then?